# Deleting user defaults under Mac OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, default-settings

Since a short time (I (guess* since Mac OS X 10.10.2) I was able to clear my settings under `NSUserDefaults` via

```
defaults delete ~/Library/Preference/<my app>.plist
```

But all of a sudden it does not work and my settings seem to be super-persistent. I also manually cleared anything under “Saved Settings” and issued the above command for “Containers” (though sandboxing was turned off for testing anyway).

What else can hold my settings? I guess the next reboot might clear it but I want to avoid rebooting in the future.

**PS** The settings did even survive a reboot :-(

Comment: That directory in the path should be "Preferences" plural.

Comment: @Spiff, Yes. It's a typo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, when using `defaults`, you must leave off the `.plist` from the filename -- it always adds that, so if you also supply it `defaults` will try to delete "<my app>.plist.plist".

Second, I think that when you specify the full path to the preference file you bypass `cfprefsd`, which (among other things) caches recently-used preferences. You should either just use `defaults delete <my app>`, or run `killall cfprefsd` before deleting the preferences (but after quitting the app).

Note that if the app is sandboxed, `defaults` is the wrong way to delete the preferences -- just kill `cfprefsd`, then use `rm` to delete either the app's entire sandbox container (`rm ~/Library/Containers/<my app>`) or just its preference file (`rm ~/Library/Containers/<my app>/Data/Library/Preferences/<my app>.plist`)

Comment: OMG. I was absolutely sure that I used it with the plist all the time. Once I did not use the suffix it worked. Thanks! Also I did not know that I can (should) leave off the full path. It works even (or maybe better) without the path. Thanks a second time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check in `~/Library/Containers/`.

I think sandboxed (App Store) apps have to store their stuff there now.

Comment: Thanks. this helped me! I was wondering why my defaults get restored even after deleting the app and reinstalling on MacOS.